# theorem dealing with order of numbers

Tags: number-theory

I'm having trouble understanding part of the proof to a theorem. The theorem states that 
Let $ord_ma = e$ and k any positive integer. Then $ord_m(a^k)$ = $e/(e,k)$.

The part I don't understand is how they conclude r|s. Here is how that part of the proof goes.
Proof: Let $ord_m(a^k) = r$ and $d = gcd(e, k)$. Then $e = sd$ and $k = td$, where s and t are positive integers such that $gcd(s, t) = 1$. Since$(a^k)^s = (a^{td})^s = (a^{sd})^t = (a^e)^t≡ 1^t ≡ 1 (mod m)$ by Theorem 10.1, $r|s$.

Theorem 10.1 just says "Let a be a positive integer such that $(a,m) = 1$ and $ord_m a = e$. Then $a^n ≡ 1 (mod m)$ if and only if $e|n$.

I do know that since $ord_ma = e$ => r|$ord_ma$ =>r|e => r|sd. But I don't get it from here how they get r|s?

Answer (score 2):

The expression is $(a^k)^s\equiv 1$.  Set $b=a^k$, so you have $b^s\equiv 1$.  By Theorem 10.1, the order of $b$ divides $s$.  But the order of $b$ is $r$.  So $r|s$.

Comment: Thanks that made it a lot more obvious now.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\rm\ E = ord\, a,\ $ $\rm\ d = gcd(E,K),\:$ so $\rm\ \color{#0a0}{E = ed,\ K = kd},\:$ and, hence, $\rm\:\color{#c00}{gcd(e,k) = 1}.\:$

$\rm\ \ (a^K)^n\! = 1 \iff E\mid nK \iff \color{#0a0}{ed\mid n k d}\,\stackrel{cancel\ d}\iff\, e\mid nk\stackrel{\color{#c00}{Euclid}}\iff \ e\mid n,\ $ by  $\rm\ \color{#c00}{e, k\,\ coprime.}$

But $\rm\ \color{#0a0}{ e = E/d} = E/gcd(E,K),\ $ thus $\rm\: (a^K)^n = 1\iff  e\mid n\iff  E/gcd(E,K)\mid n.\ \ $ **QED**

Comment: did you come up with that on your own?

Comment: @user60887 Yes, it was burned into my neurons long ago.